# OpenCV: Using the method of least squares to the red laser

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I've got a red laser (dot and linear). I want to locate it and using the least squares method get a line located closest to the image of the laser. I used [this Numpy function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) to get coefficients, Python 2.7 and OpenCV 3.1.

So, here's my code:

```
while loop == 1:
         rval, frame = vc.read()
         frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=640, height=480)

         red, green, blue = cv2.split(frame)
         rbin, thresholdImg = cv2.threshold(red, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)   

         new = np.argwhere(thresholdImg == 255)             #Get only RED pixels
         if len(new) == 0:                                   #If laser lost
             assistantView(3,assistantImg)      
         else:

             xs = []
             ys = []

             for (x,y) in new:                                  #Extract red pixels positions
                xs = np.append(xs,x)
                ys = np.append(ys,y)

             ArrayToResult = np.vstack([xs, np.ones(len(xs))]).T
             m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(ArrayToResult, ys)[0]   #Applying least squares method

             A = m
             B = c

             x1 = np.amin(xs)                   #Take "left" and "right" X-coords 
             x2 = np.amax(xs)
             ymin = int(np.amin(ys))                               
             ymax = int(np.amax(ys))

             y1 = x1*A + B              #Get line
             y2 = x2*A + B

             x1 = int(x1)
             x2 = int(x2)
             y1 = int(y1)
             y2 = int(y2)

             print(x1, y1, x2, y2)

             cv2.line(thresholdImg,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),1)                     #Draw a line
```

So, using dot-laser I had to get a straight line passing through the center of the laser image. But here's what I got: 
[image]

And with the help of **print(x1, y1, x2, y2)**, I noticed that the function is built right on them, do not correspond to the coordinates of the location of the laser. Move the camera, I noticed that the line is almost symmetrical to the image of the laser relative to the y=x. So, I have used an inverse function as follows:

```
  y1 = (x1-B) / A              
  y2 = (x2-B) / A
```

And the result is: [image]

Now Y-coords are looks like: 
4698, 29126, 3726, 805208, 19575, -1671, -2952, 13194....

The second day, I'm trying to solve this problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, are you trying to find the centre of the laser pointer?

Comment: No. I have all the pixel coordinates of the laser dot in "New" array. Then, I split them to XS and YS arrays respectively. And then I need to get a line located closest to the laser dot (the white ball). So I need a linear equation y=Ax + B and for that I use least squares method. since in this case the laser image is spherical, the line should pass through the center, as it is located as close to each point

Comment: It would help if you showed an example of what you hope to get, rather than the failed example.

Comment: I can easily give you an example how to draw lines through the centre, but it does not require a formula.

Comment: Ok. I need to get the equation of the line, which is located as close to each point of the laser. In this case, the laser has the shape of a ball, then such a line will definitely pass through the center. This I do so that when using the laser line that the camera will see something like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LdlOl.jpg, I could replace the laser image with the line.

Comment: For example, if the yellow dots here - this is an image of a linear laser, violet straight line is exactly what I need: http://courses.physics.northwestern.edu/new335/IM/nllsqf.gif

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it works, but it works. I wrote in an array XS positions of Y-coordinates and in YS X-coordinates:

```
for (x,y) in new:                  
     xs = np.append(xs,y) #was X
     ys = np.append(ys,x) #was Y
```

This way all works fine.

And this is the result: [image]

Comment: It is true, unfortunately I did not pay attention to it